# Updating lists on FrontEnd from MongoDB using mongoose and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a website where users can choose a seat on a plane in realtime. On the home page they choose their seat number which is then sent to a mongoDB databse using mongoose. However when a user selects a seat I don't want other users to be able to select the same seat from the list as it is occupied.

What am I supposed to do to only show available seats in the dropdown list on the homepage? I was thinking about using socket but I've had difficulties finding a way to know what seats are available and which are not based on the  exisiting users in the mongo database collection.

I'm using react and am relatively new to coding.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am assuming that you are handling this logic using NodeJS correct me if I am wrong.. And to be clear are you trying to find a way of figuring out the seats that are not occupied?

Comment: yes I'm using Nodejs. Yes exactly to then put that list in a dropdown on the homepage

Comment: For adding real time to your application you can check this answer that I gave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657070/keep-fetching-data-up-to-date/64658083#64658083

Answer (score 0):

So here is a possible solution that I you could explore(I am sure there surely is more solutions but currently when writing this, this is the solution I can think of).

- So I am assuming maybe you have **user model** and lets say the models is looking somewhat like this below:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   
    username:{type:String, required:true},
    email:{type:String, required:true, email},
    password:{type:String, required:true}

})
const userModel = mongoose.model('userModel', userSchema);
```

- So we have our user models all set and we uniquely can indentify a user by the **_id** given by mongoose or **email** that we set as unique.

**So now we need a plane trip model:**

```
const planeTripSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   
    from:{type:String, required:true},
    to:{type:String, required:true},
    seats:{type:Array, required:true}
});

const planeTrip = mongoose.model('planeTrip', planeTripSchema);
```

- Now we have a plane trip model.
- So now how I can you handle that you have different seats  within your array  of **seat**

**Implementation when creating plane trip to set up unique value to identify each sit:**

- So first I would install **uuid** `npm i uuid` or `yarn add uuid`
- So now this is dependent on how many people this flight can take lets assume that it takes 10 people.

**So this way might not be the most efficient solution but this what I am thinking currently when writing this**

- So now you aim to have 10 seats set before you can save the flight trip
- So then what you do is you can have 10 variables seat1-seat10(This is where this solution become inefficient) and call he `uuid` lib to get unique identifier(will give back unique number)
- Then below is how you then instantiate new flight

```
const newFlight = new planeTrip({
    
    from:'New York',
    to:'Washington DC',
    seats:[
        
        {
            occupied:false
            seat_id:<use the variable you made when using uuid for seat1-10
            seat_number:1 // You can then populate each sit number self from 1-10 on each entry but id you'll get fom uuid
            person:"",
        }
        //So you can do this 10 time because plane supports 10 seats in this exampl

    ]

})
```

- So now when you save the document to mongoDB you have seats that you can uniquely identify

**So now how then do you handle occupied sits:**

- So now in client side when you make a request to get flight sit details you will use javaScript map to map through seats array and then check if **occupied === true** as we wrote there above
- So it's true then you can leave as is
- Else if it false you can use CSS to then underline over the seat number
- Meaning that your css class must also some ternary operations
- And a normal user definitely  will know that it's occupied
- Then when user clicks on the available sit you then sit through the **sit number and sit id** that would be available easily when you mapping through the seats array
- Not forgetting you also have to send through the email of the user because in our example here we uniquely identify our users with email
- 
- Then at the back-end only thing you do is update **ocupied** of the sit ID that you got from client from **false** to **true**
- You also update the **person** from empty string to **email** received from client

**So this is a possible solution that can be improved if you sit down and think it through but at least I gave you a starting point of which direction to take but I believe this solution can be improved to being more efficient than this**